# What is the most efficient way to setup relationships between thousands of objects in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

Let's say I have inserted 10.000 Book entities and 10.000 Author entities, and need to setup one to one relationships between them. Both entities have an attribute called bookID. I do this:

1. Fetch all Books, sorted by bookID
2. Fetch all Authors, sorted by bookID
3. Enumerate the books array, and if currentBook.bookID == currentAuthor.bookID, then currentBook.author = currentAuthor. Repeat this for all books. At every 1000th book for which a relationship was just set, save the context (otherwise even more memory is consumed).

My problem is memory allocation going overboard. How do I limit that? I tried [fetchRequest setBatchSize:], setFetchLimit: in conjunction with setFetchOffset:, with no luck.

Comment: It's easier to establish a direct _book <-> author_ relationship in Core Data. Then it would be `book.author.book == book`.

Comment: Instead of fetching all authors at once, do one fetch for each book using a predicate where bookID == currentBook.bookID.  Make sure that bookID is indexed so this doesn't take forever.

Comment: Fetching an Author for each book is something I'm trying to avoid (I see fetches as being expensive).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are conceptualizing your data model correctly.  An attribute "bookID" shouldn't really be in the Author Entity.  Also it seems strange to have a one to one relationship in both ways.  More likely you would want to have a one-to-many relationship from Author to Book (an author could write multiple books), and potentially even a one-to-many relationship in the opposite direction as well (a book could have multiple authors, although that is up to you).

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't help with the OP's original problem of setting relationships without using too much memory.

Comment: I know it's strange having a bookID in an Author entity, but I couldn't find a better example. Let's say we have entity A, entity B, and a common key on which the relationship should be based.